# Как сохранить файл Document в которой находится загруженная страница в файл Java или SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

Я пишу приложение парсер, который загружает(полностью копирует) страницу из интернета в файл класса Document. После чего мне нужно сохранить данный файл каким-нибудь образом, чтобы использовать данные в режиме оффлайн. И так мой вопрос: как сохранить этот Document в SharedPreference или в файл Java? Напишите подробный ответ пожалуйста-)))

```
private void getWeb() { try { doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(http///:example.com).get();
```

Comment: Я переформулировал вопрос-)))

Comment: теперь стоит уточнить, чем «загружать (полностью копировать) в файл» отличается от «сохранять файл». да, и, заодно, чем «файл» отличается от «файл java». не надо отвечать в комментарии — правьте прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SharedPreferences

Сохранить:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit()
    .putString(KEY, doc.html()) // или doc.outerHtml(), или doc.toString(), или каким-либо другим способом
    .commit();
```

Загрузить:

```
String htmlDoc = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    .getString(KEY, null);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlDoc);
```

2. Файл в кэше:

Сохранить:

```
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename.html");
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, doc.html(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Загрузить:

```
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename.html");
String htmlDoc = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToFile(f, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlDoc);
```

Если не нравится `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`, можно записать/прочитать любым другим способом.

Comment: Я сделал все как выше описано, но выходит ошибка в имени патча org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils... Что делать?

Comment: @АзимджонХакимов возможно стоит начать с того, чтобы описать проблему более подробно.

Comment: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist Вот ошибка при запуске...

Comment: @АзимджонХакимов добавь [модуль](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) в проект

Comment: Проблема решилась при добавлении implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'   Спасибо вам за помощь, очень признателен-))

Comment: @АзимджонХакимов добавили бы последнюю версию, там же 2.11 по ссылке было. `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'`